# Java reflection inside stream's filter

Tags: java, generics, reflection, java-8, java-stream

I have an Java POJO:

```
public class Event {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Long time;
}
```

A simple filtering method I created is:

```
public static List<Event> simpleFilter(List<Event> eventList, String value) {
    return eventList.stream().filter(Event -> Event.getName().equals(value)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Now my task is to create a generic method instead of `simpleFilter` which can be applied for any Java POJO object and any of its fields. For example, if in future there is a new Java object `Employee` and we want to filter on its String field `employeeDepartment`, we can use same generic filter method by passing the List of Java object (`List<Employee>`, Class type `Employee.class`, which field (`getEmployeeDepartment`) and what value (`"Computer"`) we want to filter on.

I created a method definition:

```
public static <T> List<T> genericStringFilterOnList(List<T> list, Class<T> c, String methodName, String value) {
}
```

Caller looks like:

```
//events is List<Event>
//getName is the method in Event on which I want to filter
//e2 is value which I want to filter
genericStringFilterOnList(events, Event.class, "getName", "e2")
```

My implementation is:

```
public static <T> List<T> genericStringFilterOnList(List<T> list, Class<T> c, String methodName, String value) {
    return list.stream().filter(m -> {
        try {
            return c.getMethod(methodName, null).invoke(c).equals(value);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
        }
        return false;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

All these catch were generated by IDE because of checked exception.
This doesn't seem to working because it is returning back an empty list.
What I am trying to do here is - Using the class type (which is `Event.class`), I am getting method name using reflection and then invoking that method and then invoke which is basically calling `getName()` method of Event class and then equals. I also tried this -

```
return c.getMethod(methodName, null).invoke(c.newInstance()).equals(value);
```

But with this I am getting NPE on this

```
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Can you please help me in creating a generic method which can be called for a List of any POJO and a filter can be applied on any of its String type methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invocation should happen on the steamed item, not on the class itself. The method [`Method::invoke(Object obj, Object... args)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) has two parameters:

- `obj` - the object the underlying method is invoked from
- `args` - the arguments used for the method call

Change the line:

```
return c.getMethod(methodName, null).invoke(c).equals(value);
```

.. to:

```
return c.getMethod(methodName, null).invoke(m).equals(value);
```

The confusion comes from the *one-lettered variable names* (see the solution below).

---

The whole solution shall be simplified. You don't want to extract the very same `Method` through reflection for the each object present in the stream pipeline. Extract the `Method` first and reuse it:

```
static <T> List<T> genericStringFilterOnList(List<T> list, Class<T> clazz, String method, String value) {
    try {
        // reflection invoked just once
        Method method = clazz.getMethod(method, null);
        // now streaming of the n items
        return list.stream().filter(item -> {
            try { 
                return value.equals(method.invoke(item));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {}
            return false;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {}
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

---

(Out of scope of this question): Note there is a higher probability that the invoked method returns `null` than the passed `value` is, therefore I'd go for `value.equals(method.invoke(item))`. Maybe, you want to add some additional comparison condition when both values are `null` to be compared.